# Analytic solution inverse kinematics - different solutions with different calculation steps

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, systems-of-equations, inverse-problems, robotics

I have the following problem:

$$5\cos \theta_1+3\sqrt{3}\sin \theta_1=4\qquad\qquad\textbf{(I)}$$
$$5\sin \theta_1-3\sqrt{3}\cos \theta_1=6\qquad\qquad\textbf{(II)}$$

I have two seemingly correct paths to a solution, however only one actually computes the correct one.

Path 1, yielding the correct solution (I$\cdot$5, II $\cdot-3\sqrt{3}$):
$$25 \cos\theta_1 + 15 \sqrt{3} \sin\theta_1
    = 20$$
$$-15 \sqrt{3} \sin\theta_1 + 27 \cos\theta_1
    = -18\sqrt{3}$$
Add both:
$$52 \cos\theta_1 = 20 - 18\sqrt{3}$$
$$\theta_1=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{20-18\sqrt{3}}{52}\right)\approx1.7874$$

Path 2, resulting in a different solution, that doesn't even satisfy the system of equations(I $\cdot3\sqrt{3}$, II $\cdot5$):
$$15 \sqrt{3} \cos\theta_1 + 27 \sin\theta_1
    = 12 \sqrt{3}$$
$$25 \sin\theta_1 - 15 \sqrt{3} \cos\theta_1
    = 30$$
Add both:
$$52 \sin\theta_1 = 30 + 12\sqrt{3}$$
$$\theta_1 = \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{15 + 6\sqrt{3}}{26} \right)
\approx 1.3542$$
$$5\cos(1.3542)+3\sqrt{3}\sin(1.3542)=6.1493\neq4$$

I don't see any errors in both solutions, however only the first path calculates the correct value. How can this be? How is this generalizable (or not) to the solutions of systems of equations with sin/cos in them?

Comment: The cos is negative and the sin is positive, so the angle is in the second quadrant the arcsin function only gives the solution that is in the first quadrant.

Answer (score 1):

For this system, I would set $\sigma=\sin \theta_1,\chi=\cos\theta_1$ and work those out rather than throwing yourself into inverse trig functions of irrationals so early.

$$3\sqrt 3 \sigma +5\chi =4 \tag I$$$$5\sigma-3\sqrt 3 \chi=6\tag {II}$$

Applying $(I)* 3\sqrt 3, (II)*5$ as in your second choice, we get: $$27\sigma+15\sqrt 3\chi=12\sqrt3 \tag{III}$$$$25\sigma-15\sqrt3 \chi =30 \tag{IV}$$
yielding $\sigma =\frac{6\sqrt 3+15}{26}$ and $\chi=\frac{10-9\sqrt 3}{26}$

You can calculate that $\sigma^2+\chi^2=1$ indeed.

You can then solve and see that picking the *second* solution of $\sin \theta= \frac{6\sqrt3+15}{26}$, where $\theta \approx1.787$ gives the correct answer here.

Comment: But why is there a "wrong" solution in the first place?

Comment: @meschi Because $\sin^2 x + \cos^2x =1$, there are two distinct values for $\cos x$ per given $\sin x$: $\cos x =\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}$